# SSL certificate working everywhere except Safari

Tags: apache, ssl, npm, https

I have installed an SSL certificate I generated from Let's Encrypt using Nginx Proxy Manager. The cert works great on everything except Safari! I get a "cannot parse response" in Safari.

My setup is as following:
I have ports 80/443 open to my NPM instance, where I then proxy over to the correct machine running the web server. I have HTTPS forced for eataupa.com and also HTTPS forced between NPM and my web server. I am not sure if Im suppose to run this inside connection between NPM HTTPs or HTTP.

Either way eataupa.com works fine unless its safari and im tearing my hair out trying to fix it!

Please help, thanks so much!

I see some error produced here I just dont know how to interpret and fix it.
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=eataupa.com

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer from a TLS stand point, I cannot tell you which config to change since I am not familiar with your applications.

The Safari versions that could not connect to your website probably do not support the security requirements such as the protocol version and many other things such as cipher suites.

This most likely occurs because of the ciphers, as Safari 8 seems to support TLS 1.2 but it still fails to perform the TLS handshake.

Here are the list of Safari 8 ciphers: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=Safari&version=8&platform=iOS%208.4

And you would sometimes need the OpenSSL interpretation of them: https://testssl.sh/openssl-iana.mapping.html

You need to configure your server to use one of the cipher suites that those safari versions support.